# How to skip some lines while sorting a file content using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have written a following script to sort file content based on some column.

```
$lines = Get-Content $inputFile

foreach($line in $lines){
    if($line.startsWith('*') -or $line.startsWith('-')){
        continue
    }
    if(($line -eq $lines[0])  -or ($line -eq $lines[1]) -or ($line -eq $lines[2])){
        Sort-Object { $line.Substring(70,9) } | set-content $outputFile
    }
}
```

input file content:

```
 ...header row...
 ...header row...
 ...header row...
        4
        2
        1
 ....trailor.....
```

Desired Output:

```
 ...header row...
 ...header row...
 ...header row...
        1
        2
        3
 ....trailor.....
```

In my input file, I have first three lines as header and Lat line as trailer. I want to skip these lines while sorting. I tried to use above script. But it's not skipping those lines. Can someone correct me for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always want to skip the first three and last one line, you could also adopt your foreach loop:

```
foreach ($line in $lines[3 .. ($lines.Count -2)])
{
    Write-Host $line
}
```

Your `foreach` loop will now starts on the forth element and runs until the line before the last line.

**Edit:** 
Here a solution for your example where I create a new array and just sort the specific lines using the [Sort-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113403) cmdlet (alias sort) and finally set the new content using the [Set-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113392) cmdlet:

```
$lines = Get-Content $inputFile
@($lines[0 .. 2], ($lines[3 .. ($lines.Count -2)] | Sort-Object -Descending), $lines[-1]) | Set-Content $outputFile
```

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your response! Could you please give command with Sort-Objet, because in my case alos I am skipping but it's not working. SO I want to try your command

Comment: You have to share us an example and tell us the desired output. Otherwise, im not able to help you.

Comment: Yes, I added a 2-liner solution that does exactly what you want.

Comment: You are welcome. I removed the `$line.Substring` from your edit since that won't work here.